# Cannot cast java.util.date to java.sql.date

Tags: java, date

I have the following code snippet where i get continous error for casting java.util.date to java.sql.date.

```
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        storedProcedureCall.setLong(1, 12345);
        storedProcedureCall.setDate(2, (java.sql.Date) sdf.parse("09/02/2017"));
        storedProcedureCall.setDate(3, (java.sql.Date) sdf.parse("10/02/2017"));
```

What am i doing wrong here. I have imported the java.util.Date package as well.

Comment: Any reason why you are using the long outdated classes `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`? I recommend [the modern Java date and time API known as JSR-310 or `java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). You can pass a `LocalDate` or other modern object to `PreparedStatement.setObject()`, also when using the `CallableStatement` subinterface, of course.

Comment: `java.sql.Date` extends (is a subclass of) `java.util.Date`. The `parse()` method returns a `java.util.Date`, and you can't cast it to a subclass: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30414859/how-to-cast-subclass-object-to-superclass-object

Answer (score 1):

The class `java.util.Date` is totally different to `java.sql.Date`. Thus it can not be cast to.

You probably meant to use `java.util.Date`. Check your signature of `storedProcedureCall#setDate`, it probably accidentally imported `java.sql.Date` instead of `java.util.Date`.

---

Note that nowadays the `Date` class should not be used anymore. Instead use the new modern API located inside the package `java.time`. Like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(dateAsString, formatter);
```

Comment: Incorrect, `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date` are *not* “totally different”. Unfortunately, just the opposite. `java.sql.Date` inherits from `java.util.Date`. So while `java.sql.Date` pretends to hold only a date without a time-of-day and without a time zone, it does indeed hold both a time-of-day and a time zone. Actually *two* time zones — while the date-time tracked as a count from UTC (and therefore represents a moment in UTC), there actually is a time zone assigned deep in the source code without any getter/setter. Total train wreck of bad design. Use *java.time* instead.